# How do I get this twitter feed to render in my React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter

I'm new to React. I've been using it for about two weeks now.

I'm trying to get this Twitter feed to render on my React component but I'm not sure how.

**Problem:** When I click on the navbar link to get to this page, all that shows up is my login component.

Heres the code for the twitter feed. Any idea why and how I can fix this to just show the feed?

```html
<a
  class="twitter-timeline"
  data-lang="en"
  data-theme="dark"
  href={"https://twitter.com/MTA?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%22%7D%3ETweets"}
>
</a> 
<script
  async
  src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"
  charset="utf-8"
></script>
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be like this? `href={"https://twitter.com/MTA?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">%3ETweets by MTA</a>`

Comment: Actually I think I was able to fix this component to where it renders. But the problem now is, instead of rendering the actual twitter feed, it renders a button or a link that says "Tweets by the mta" instead of the actual twitter feed itself. @Steven and yeahhh thats what I got from the documentation I think

Answer (score 1):

Was actually able to get this fixed. It's still a bit buggy but I realized I was missing a few packages that I should've downloaded